# Differences between LLR and emulate 2-PC in weblogic server

Tags: transactions, weblogic, weblogic9.x

First, are those protocols ? or transaction types ?
Second, what's the main differences between them ?
This is what oracle talks about Last Logging Resource:

> With this option, the transaction branch in which the connection is used is processed as the >last resource in the transaction and is processed as a one-phase commit operation. The >result of the operation is written in a log file on the resource itself, and the result >determines the success or failure of the prepare phase of the transaction.

And about Emulate Two-Phase Commit

> With this option, the transaction branch in which the connection is used always returns >success for the prepare phase of the transaction.

Not quite clear about this, someone please help me to make it clear.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This all has to do with how gobal transactions (XA) works:

**Understanding the Emulate Two-Phase Commit Transaction Option**

If you need to support distributed transactions with a JDBC data source, but there is no available XA-compliant driver for your DBMS, you can select the Emulate Two-Phase Commit for non-XA Driver option for a data source to emulate two-phase commit for the transactions

**Understanding the Logging Last Resource Transaction Option**

WebLogic Server supports the Logging Last Resource (LLR) transaction optimization through JDBC data sources. LLR is a performance enhancement option that enables one non-XA resource to participate in a global transaction with the same ACID guarantee as XA. LLR is a refinement of the "Last Agent Optimization." It differs from Last Agent Optimization in that it is transactionally safe.

---

You will almost always want to use LLR unless that is just not an option because of your jdbc driver. Note in the links there is no 'advantages' section for 2 phase commit emulation.

[Understanding emulate 2 phase commite](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/transactions.htm#i1146298)

[Understanding LLR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24367/transactions.htm#i1145819)